# Zend Db Float Problem

Tags: zend-framework, types, floating-point, zend-db

I have a MySQL table structured:
float(10,2)

For example I insert a row.

```
$value = array('price' => '13539.51');
$db->insert($value);
```

When I check this row with phpmyadmin, everything is fine. But when I read this row with Zend Db, price value like this "13539.509765625". How can i fix this problem.

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->where('id = ?' 1);
echo $db->fetchRow($select)->price;
//13539.509765625
```

Comment: Very strange. What is displayed when you make a var_dump on $db->fetchRow($select)->price ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue lies with the data type you chose for your column and not Zend_Db.
You might want to alter it to be a DECIMAL(10,2).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Cheers,
Angel

Comment: Yes, for money it's better than float.